# serviceaccounts "zookeeper-operator" already exists

Tags: kubernetes, solr, apache-zookeeper

I am using [solr-operator v0.3.0](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-solr/solr-operator/0.3.0) but trying not to use zookeeper-operator comes with that. I am overriding values file like below.

```
solr:
  replicaCount: 1

  image:
    repository: apache/solr-operator
    tag: v0.3.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  nameOverride: ""
  fullnameOverride: ""

  zookeeper-operator:
    install: false
    use: true
    crd:
      create: false

  watchNamespaces: ""

  rbac:
    create: true

  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: zookeeper-operator
```

I am using [zookeeper operator](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/banzaicloud-stable/zookeeper-operator) as a separate helm chart.

```
zookeeper:
  image:
    repository: pravega/zookeeper-operator
    tag: 0.2.10
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  rbac:
    create: true

  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: zookeeper-operator

  crd:
    create: true
```

Both those helm charts are dependencies of one of my custom helm chart.

```
dependencies:
  - name: zookeeper
    version: 0.1.x
    repository: "@private_repo"
  - name: solr
    version: 0.1.x
    repository: "@private_repo"
```

But when I try to install that helm chart, it will give following error.

**serviceaccounts "zookeeper-operator" already exists**

If I comment *solr* dependency and install the helm chart first and then uncomment the *solr* part and reinstall it, then I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the Solr Operator slack channel.

This is a problem with the private Solr helm repo being used. If the open source charts are used as dependencies, then the deployment works as expected.

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: zookeeper-operator
    repository: https://charts.pravega.io
    version: 0.2.10
  - name: solr-operator
    repository: https://solr.apache.org/charts
    version: 0.3.0
```

If there is a necessity to use intermediate helm charts that depend on the open source charts, then make sure to:

- Put the values under the sub-chart name and sub-sub-chart name, i.e. solr -> solr-operator -> values and zookeeper -> zookeeper-operator -> values.
- Make sure that the intermediate helm charts do not contain any CRDs managed by the open source charts.

```yaml
solr:
  solr-operator:
    replicaCount: 1

    image:
      repository: apache/solr-operator
      tag: v0.3.0
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

    nameOverride: ""
    fullnameOverride: ""

    zookeeper-operator:
      install: false
      use: true
      crd:
        create: false

    watchNamespaces: ""

    rbac:
      create: true

    serviceAccount:
      create: false
      name: zookeeper-operator
```

and

```yaml
zookeeper:
  zookeeper-operator:
    image:
      repository: pravega/zookeeper-operator
      tag: 0.2.10
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

    rbac:
      create: true

    serviceAccount:
      create: true
      name: zookeeper-operator

    crd:
      create: true
```